# Request object persistence between class methods

Tags: python

When I run this code using a unittest, the `print(self.req.text)` statement in the `get_page()` method works as expected, but the one in the `get_html()` method produces an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`. I'd like to know why that is. Have I made a mistake or is there something to do with request responses that mean they can't be stored in a class in the way I've tried to do? If so, it's not obvious to me from reading the package documentation. Many thanks.

```
from . import helpers
import requests, bs4

class Page(object):
    """Page """

    def __init__(self, url=None):
        self.url = url
        self.req = None
        self.html = None
        self.soup = None

    def get_page(self, url):
        self.req = requests.get(url)
        print(self.req.text) # This works
        return self.req

    def get_html(self):
        print(self.req.text) # This errors
        self.html = self.req.text
        return self.html
```

Comment: Did you call `get_page` before `get_html`? Otherwise `self.req` was not set yet.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand now: it's because unittest runs setUp and tearDown for every test, not once for each class of tests as I mistakenly thought. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `self.req = None` in the `__init__` seems to be the cause.

You have two choices

- make sure that `get_page()` is administered before `get_html`
- rewrite your `self.req = None` in the `__init__` to `self.req = self.get_page()`